# Parsing for specific information

Tags: text-processing

I run a command on my linux system and redirect the output into a file.
Here is what my file looks like:

```
client: tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-tuvwxyza
        version: xxxx
        uuid: abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-tuvwxyza
        user-uid: 10000
        user: someuser
        primary-server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        operational-mode: normal
        mac: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
        locked-time: xx:xx:xx
        ipaddr: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        hostname: tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-tuvwxyza
        connection-1: frdp::Green::Test
        connection-0: frdp::Purple::Test
client: tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-abcdefgh
        version: xxxx
        uuid: abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-abcedfgh
        user-uid: 10000
        user: someuser
        primary-server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        operational-mode: normal
        mac: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
        locked-time: xx:xx:xx
        ipaddr: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        hostname: tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-abcdefgh
        connection-0: frdp::Purple::Test
client: tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-ijklmnop
        version: xxxx
        uuid: abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-ijklmnop
        user-uid: 10000
        user: someuser
        primary-server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        operational-mode: normal
        mac: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
        locked-time: xx:xx:xx
        ipaddr: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        hostname: tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-ijklmnop
client: tc-abcdefg-higj-klmn-opqr-qrstuvwx
        version: xxxx
        uuid: abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-qrstuvwx
        user-uid: 10000
        user: someuser
        primary-server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        operational-mode: normal
        mac: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
        locked-time: xx:xx:xx
        ipaddr: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        hostname: tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-qrstuvwx
        connection-0: frdp::Purple::Test
client: tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-12345678
        version: xxxx
        uuid: abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-12345678
        user-uid: 10000
        user: someuser
        primary-server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        operational-mode: normal
        mac: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
        locked-time: xx:xx:xx
        ipaddr: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        hostname: tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-12345678
        connection-0: frdp::Green::Test
client: tc-abcdefg-higj-klmn-opqr-09876543
        version: xxxx
        uuid: abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-09876543
        user-uid: 10000
        user: someuser
        primary-server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        operational-mode: normal
        mac: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
        locked-time: xx:xx:xx
        ipaddr: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        hostname: tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-09876543
        connection-0: frdp::Purple::Test
client: tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-135792468
        version: xxxx
        uuid: abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-135792468
        user-uid: 10000
        user: someuser
        primary-server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        operational-mode: normal
        mac: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
        locked-time: xx:xx:xx
        ipaddr: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        hostname: tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-135792468
        connection-0: frdp::Green::Test
client: tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-08649753
        version: xxxx
        uuid: abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-08649753
        user-uid: 10000
        user: someuser
        primary-server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        operational-mode: normal
        mac: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
        locked-time: xx:xx:xx
        ipaddr: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        hostname: tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-08649753
        connection-0: frdp::Purple::Test
```

I want to extract the client hostnames that show only a connection to Purple and clients with no connections into a new file. I have had some success getting all of the non-relevant information out using the following:

```
awk -F '\t' '/^client: / || /connection/' myfile1 >> myfile2
```

I have not been able extract just those clients with a connection to purple or no connection. I want to omit everything that has a connection to Green, even if the client had a connection to Purple.

EDIT: Here is what I get when using awk

```
client: tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-tuvwxyza
        connection-1: frdp::Green::Test
        connection-0: frdp::Purple::Test
client: tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-abcdefgh
        connection-0: frdp::Purple::Test
client: tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-ijklmnop
client: tc-abcdefg-higj-klmn-opqr-qrstuvwx
        connection-0: frdp::Purple::Test
client: tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-12345678
        connection-0: frdp::Green::Test
client: tc-abcdefg-higj-klmn-opqr-09876543
        connection-0: frdp::Purple::Test
client: tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-135792468
        connection-0: frdp::Green::Test
client: tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-08649753
        connection-0: frdp::Purple::Test
```

EDIT: I did not take into consideration my lack of clarity. The output I am looking for should look like this:

```
tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-abcdefgh
tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-ijklmnop
tc-abcdefg-higj-klmn-opqr-qrstuvwx
tc-abcdefg-higj-klmn-opqr-09876543
tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-08649753
```

I only want the 5 clients that only a connection to Purple and no connection present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```bsh
$ tr -s '\n' ' ' < file | \
  sed 's/client:/\n/g' | \
  grep -o 'hostname: [^ ]\+ connection-0.*Purple\|hostname: [^ ]\+ $' | \
  cut -d' ' -f2
tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

---

- `$ tr -s '\n' ' '` converts the file to a single string.
- `sed 's/client:/\n/g'` replaces "client" for newline.
- `grep -o 'hostname: [^ ]\+ connection-0.*Purple\|hostname: [^ ]\+ $'` captures the lines that have "connection-0...Purple" or the lines that don't have connections.

  ```
  hostname: tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx connection-0: frdp::Purple
  hostname: tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx 
  hostname: tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx connection-0: frdp::Purple
  hostname: tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx connection-0: frdp::Purple
  hostname: tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx connection-0: frdp::Purple
  ```
- `cut -d' ' -f2` print only the hostnames.

---

To write to a new file append  `> newfile`.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 == "client:" {
    prt()
}
/connection/ {
    gotConns = 1
    if ( /Purple/ ) {
        gotTarget = 1
    }
    else {
        gotOther = 1
    }
}
$1 == "hostname:" {
    host = $2 ORS
}
END {
    prt()
}

function prt(   found) {
    if ( (gotTarget && !gotOther) || !gotConns ) {
        printf "%s", host
    }
    host = gotConns = gotTarget = gotOther = ""
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-abcdefgh
tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-ijklmnop
tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-qrstuvwx
tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-09876543
tc-abcdefgh-igjk-lmno-pqrs-08649753
```